# Chrome Dev Tools Source Link Manipulation

Tags: javascript, console, google-chrome-devtools, console.log

To have better control over my debugging messages I created a wrapper for console.log which I have defined in `debug.js` and call via `debug.log()`. But when I let the wrapper log some message to the console, the link now points to the definition of my wrapper and not anymore to the code where the logging function is called from.

So every link in my console looks now this way

```
debug.js:27
debug.js:27
debug.js:27
```

This makes it pretty hard to find the correct location in the source code to set breakpoints.

Is there a way to let console print the link to the location of the origin of the debug.log execution?

Comment: Try [console.groupCollapsed](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-reference#consolegroupcollapsedobject_object) and use the message as a group title and a [stack trace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/trace) inside.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks. It doesn't look pretty but it helps for the time being :-)